# Wanted to run ant script from Maven

Tags: java, maven, ant

[image]

[image]

JAVA_HOME is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45".. Still it is showing value till jre.

```
I have added tools.jar in Ant->Runtime->Globle Entries
Also verified that installed jre is having path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45"
Copied "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\lib\tools.jar" to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\" folder

Is there any other solution to this problem?
```

Comment: As per the error suggests you're not pointing to a JDK. You need to change JAVA_HOME to be the root of your JDK and not the JRE.

Comment: it is pointing to jdk only....But not knowing how it is taking path till jre

Comment: Why do you like to run an Ant script from Maven? What is the purpose of that?

Comment: Please post the main content of your request as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

You must either include the `ant-contrib*.jar` into your Ant installation (into the `<ant_home>/lib` directory), or either include an explicit `<classpath>` in your `build.xml`:

```
<taskdef resource="...">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="my_dir/ant-contrib.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

See http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/#install